# Django Rest - Return All Value @api_view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to return `All Value` rather than access array like this `UserHistorySerializer(queryset[1])`

**`My Code`**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_history(request):
    queryset = User.history.all()
    serializer_class = UserHistorySerializer(queryset[1])
    return Response({"message": serializer_class.data})
```

I tried to **create functions** to ****return value**** however i got ***only one*** Value.

```
def history_list(queryset):
    value = []
    for data in queryset:
        return data

@parser_classes([MultiPartParser, JSONParser])
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_history(request):
    queryset = User.history.all()
    serializer_class = UserHistorySerializer(history_list(queryset))
    return Response({"message": serializer_class.data})
```

I also tried to make change ***function*** something like below.

```
def history_list(queryset):
    for data in queryset:
        return [value for value in data]
```

However, i got error `object is not iterable`.

I'll appreciate of all ur help. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`many=True`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-multiple-objects) argument to serialize many objects at once:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_history(request):
    queryset = User.history.all()
    serializer_class = UserHistorySerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response({"message": serializer_class.data})
```